# "based on a true story" in German

Tags: translation

"Based on a True Story" is a sentence that is shown before or after films and television shows to inform the viewers that the program is adapted from real events.

What is the translation of this phrase to German?

Comment: I wonder where is @User uknown to do his duty, isn't this general reference?

Comment: @Gigili Acutally, you're right. I found the answer on page one of the Google search result to ["based on a true story german"](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=webhp&q=based+on+a+true+story+german&oq=based+on+a+true+story+german&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...3712.4687.2.4896.7.7.0.0.0.0.175.866.3j4.7.0...0.0.Yiyiv4FkTtk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=9d9a8f7f79615f2e&biw=1680&bih=900). Therefore, voted to close the question as general reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=based%20on%20a%20true%20story) says is correct:

> "nach einer wahren Geschichte" or "nach einer wahren Begebenheit"

Comment: Personally, I like the 2nd variant with "Begebenheit" better (which is not on dict.cc!).

Comment: Indeed. "wahre Geschichte" sounds a bit like an oxymoron.

Comment: How so? I feel there are more *Geschichten* that aren't *wahr* than *Begebenheiten* that aren't *wahr*.